# remove zeros from the middle of the filename

Tags: rename, filenames

I have a bunch of files that are of this form: abc_512_004.dat
all i need to do is to delete the zeros so that the filename becomes abc_512_4.dat

I have tried all kinds of things including rename 's/^0+//' *.dat and cannot seem to know what to do.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use replace method. You could do

```
'abc_512_004.dat'.replace("0","");
```

This will result in 'abc_512_4.dat'. Let me know if it didn't helps.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot but that does not work: Badly placed ()'s.